# Prevent green parrots dominating the bird feeder

Tags: birds

We have a number of bird feeders hanging in our garden, and a reasonable number of different, interesting bird species visit them. We regularly see Blue Tits, Coal Tits, Woodpeckers, etc., as well as the usual starlings, etc.

There are large flocks of green parrots where we are, and several times a day, one or two of them will hog the bird feeders and chase off the other birds.

Is there anything we can do about this? We'd like to encourage more of the interesting species to visit, and discourage the parrots.

Location: West London.

Comment: When we humans take to feeding the wildlife we had better be prepared for learning we aren't in control.  This I know all too well.  All animals want to survive, even those we humans deem as less interesting.  Flocks of green parrots being a problem??  When disturbing the natural course of things we need to be glad we can help other species survive.  You do not want to control.  You want to be educated by nature and what your input is able to change...usually for the worst.  Play with different feeders with different types of food for different birds. All birds are beautiful and valuable...all

Answer (score 4):

One option might be to use a [feeder cage](https://www.birdfood.co.uk/large-feeder-guardian-cage.html). This will prevent larger birds from being able to get at the feeder, so should stop parakeets from being able to feed, but but the side effect that it will also prevent some other birds

Answer (score 1):

According  to the RSPB  (https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/bird-and-wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/r/ringneckedparakeet/feeding.aspx), it's likely that parakeets in the London area survive well because they can forage for food, with bird feeders being a primary source. In the UK, they have become omnivorous, so will also take scraps of all sorts.

Their beaks are such that it's next to impossible for them to feed from a good nut feeder - I'm in West London too, and they never attempt to feed from my steel and terracotta one - but will come and eat scraps, nuts and seeds strewn on a tray or bird table outdoors. I'd compromise - use nut feeders (not just wire cage ones, the squirrels will be in those in a heartbeat) and put out other nuts and bird seed in the other feeders you're using. Despite the racket they make, they are a colourful addition to the birds we've always seen here, and can be very entertaining; its the starlings that drive me mad with bird food, most of it gets dropped and spread everywhere, very messy, noisy, squabbling birds. But, they need to eat as well when the weather's very cold, so I put up with them!